# Is there a way to copy a bug submitted in one mantis bug tracker instance to another?

Tags: defect-tracking, php

Our problem is development has multiple mantis bug tracking databases that contain multiple projects for multiple products. From a QA perspective we would like to submit a bug only once in our version of mantis and then depending on the category of the bug have it auto submitted to the developers mantis instance.

I have scoured the net for an answer to this but have not be able to find anything.

Answer (score 3):

Phil is right with how customizable it is.  After a quick search, I found a couple of export/import plugins.

A more important question may be however, why are the testers using a separate instance from the developers?  Doing a constant export/import is just going to create additional overhead.  It's all fine and well if you update once, but, wouldn't the end goal to have them in sync, in which case, you'd also need a service or something else monitoring for changes.

Comment: Thanks Lyndon. I was able to get an idea of what you are seeing. I guess my google search need to be more percise.                            hehe. You hit the nail on the head. Yes, we are working towards a common bug tracking system. Our company recently merged and after the dust settled there were 5 independent development groups (all using separate databases) and only 1 QA group which was newly formed. our current project involves 4 of those dev groups and everyone is unwilling to move to a common db, so i am looking for alternative solutions.

Comment: Ah, now I understand, and feel for you.  The first one that I found was this one which looks like it would do what you need.  http://bugtracker.morinie.fr/mantis/dokuwiki/doku.php?id=mantis:13:start

Comment: Great, That is the one I started looking at. Thanks again for your input.

Answer (score 2):

Mantis is totally customisable so you could probably get someone to code a solution up - the database is open and the code is there for you to do whatever you want. It does mean coding in php though...

Comment: Thanks for the response Phil. We are under a very tight resource constraint so a customized soultion is a great suggestion, not sure we will be able to implement it. I was hoping there was a plugin or something that was already written or possibly a setting in mantis itself.